# How to set padding and text type face using style.xml in android

Tags: android

```
 val textView = TextView(context)
        textView.text = "This is my message for title text  "
        context?.let {
            textView.setPadding(
                convertDpToPx(it, 24f),
                convertDpToPx(it, 24f),
                convertDpToPx(it, 24f),
                0
            )
            textView.setTypeface(textView.typeface, Typeface.BOLD);
        }

private fun convertDpToPx(context: Context, dp: Float): Int {
        return (dp * context.resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()
    }
```

I  want to be set padding  using a style that I need to define in style.xml
please suggest it possible that can we set padding and typeface bold  style and we can read that style in class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are setting it to a TextView, you can simply create a style like this

```xml
<style name="TextViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
        <item name="android:paddingTop">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
```

And assign it as easily as this

```xml
style="@style/TextViewStyle"
```

Edit: Since you do not have a TextView in XML as such, this is the only way beside that

```kotlin
val textView = TextView(yourContext, null, 0, R.style.your_style);
```

Comment: I might have understood you wrong. You do have a XML where there is a TextView correct @AmritaThakur

Comment: NO, we dont have XML we have define like this val textView = TextView(context)

Comment: @AmritaThakur, I am updating the answer for same.